# Combinatorial proof of the fact $p$ doesn't divide $ n \choose p^k$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, alternative-proof

Let $p^k | n$ and $p^{k+1} \nmid n$. Is there any combinatorial proof of the fact that $p \nmid {n \choose p^{k}} $ ?

Comment: What's wrong with the usual proof, given that it's only 1 line?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the usual proof, but I was wondering if there is a proof based on interpreting $n \choose p^k$ as the number of  $p^k$ element subsets of a $n$ element subset.

Comment: I'm not sure there will be a good one, since I don't know a good combinatorial interpretation of $a\not\mid b$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one.
I'm bad at describing combinatorics without pictures, so please comment if something doesn't make sense.

Consider arrangments in which $n$ different people sit at a circular table with $n$ places, and $p^k$ of them have plates in front of them.  We count the number of such arrangments in two different ways.

First, trivially, we count ${n \choose p^k}$ such arrangements.

Second, partition all possible arrangments into groups of arrangements (equivalence classes, really) such that two arrangements belong to the same group iff one is just a rotation of the other.
Then if some group contains, say, $m$ arrangements, we have $m | n$.
Letting $n = p^k a$, this means that *modulo $p$, we don't care about most groups*, because most groups contribute a multiple of $p$ arrangements.

What groups do we care about?  Well, we care about when $m | n = p^k a$ but $p \nmid m$.
This implies $m | a$, which means arrangements in the group must be unchanged when rotated by $a$.
The only arrangements unchanged under rotation by $a$ are those consisting of $p^k$ equally-spaced plates, and all such arrangements belong to the same group.
This group contributes $a$ distinct equally-spaced arrangements,
so the total number of arrangements is congruent to $a$ modulo $p$.

Thus, we have shown that
$$
{p^k a \choose p^k} \equiv a \pmod {p}
$$

In particular, if $p^{k+1} \nmid n$ we have that $p \nmid a$ so
$$
p \nmid {n \choose p^k}.
$$

Comment: +1. The language of group actions and orbits is perfect for this sort of argument: there is an induced action of the subgroup $C_{p^k}\le C_n$ on the space $\Gamma$ of $p^k$-subsets of $C_n$, the orbits are either size $1$ or size a power of $p$, so $\Gamma$ is congruent to the # of fixed points mod $p$, the fixed points are precisely cosets of $C_{p^k}$ within $C_n$, of which there are $n/p^k\not\equiv0$ hence $|\Gamma|\equiv n/p^k\not\equiv0$ mod $p$.

Comment: @anon what is group $C_n$?

Comment: @Mohan that would be the cyclic group of order $n$.  It can also be described as the set of integers modulo $p$ under addition.

Comment: Also, I meant *set of integers modulo $n$.